# Typescript not show error when assign value is not declared in interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am declaring an interface for my array object but when I assigning the `age` field in array object with value not exists in User interface, it never show error. How I can fix it?

```
export interface User {
    username: string;
    fullname: string;
    age: number
}


const test1: User = {
    username: 'dog',
    fullname: 'dog',
    age: 'i dont know' // error will show here
};


const test2: User[] = [
   {
      username: 'dog',
      fullname: 'dog',
      age: 'i dont know' // error never show
   },
]
```

Comment: Error is showing in both places `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)`

Comment: you should test it in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgVQGc04BvAWACg4a4BXYqJTAW2AC45CYpkBzANxVacdHQA245m07deSQcNqY+HOEjosARmioBfKocrYISbnFTcAjJyIkAvGSU0GaaWoDkAEwh8PAGmdRCSlWTx8-QOplVU4PBDgfFDgAayQIAHcPOAB6HLg0KGg4DIRJLgALTLgKtGB9IUojEzN4SxgAJltGAG0AXThHHucKaJFXJjC4iICgmjFJd2nfWbGYzwSk+DTM7LyCqCKodWAANxJCKoznPSi+oA)

Comment: @DecPK it never show in my VSCode

Comment: Ideally it should show in default settigs but it is not then you might have to configure or install extra extensions.

Comment: Well.. sometimes VSCode does that, I have experienced it. It is an issue with intellisense. Try updating or re-installing VSCode. If you are on Mac, Move the VSCode to Applications instead of running the app directly from the Download directory or any other directories.